# Change campaign of created Campaign members

Tags: lead-conversion, campaign, campaign-member

I have a workflow that create a lead and a linked campaign members into a campaign .
The fact is this flow come from a package i can't change it (lead capture).
I want after the creation change the campaign of the created campaign members but the problem is the field CampaignId is not writeable, when i clone the camapign members to update it the campaign memebers can't be modified because he can't point to a converted lead ...

someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't configure the package to specify the desired campaignId ...

Each [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm) has two fields:

- `ContactId`
- `LeadId`

When you clone the `CampaignMember`,

- Set `LeadId` to the clone source `LeadId` if the Lead is not converted, otherwise, set to `NULL`
- If the clone source's Lead is converted, then query that converted [Lead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) to find its `Lead.ConvertedContactId`. Use that value to set the cloned `CampaignMember.ContactId`

Comment: thanks but my client have a lot of dev that use the fields LeadId . I think the best way is to clone lead and campaign

Comment: Ok, but why clone a converted lead into an unconverted lead?  Perhaps I don’t understand your business problem as described.